# Problems testing user verification view

Tags: django, django-testing

I'm writing tests for my user verification view and I faced some problem that I don't know how to solve yet.
So, here is a view I'm testing:

```
def verify(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_verified = True
        user.save()
        print(user.is_verified)
        return HttpResponse('Your account was activated!')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

It's working fine when I run server and user gets his `is_activated` set to `True`

But, here is a test:

```
    def test_new_user_verification(self):
        new_user = User.objects.create_user('humapen4@gmail.com', 'Abc1234567')
        # visit activation link
        link = reverse('verify',
                       kwargs={'uidb64': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(new_user.pk)).decode(),
                               'token': account_activation_token.make_token(new_user)})
        resp = self.client.get(link)

        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTrue(new_user.is_verified)
```

First test passes fine, but the second one fails because in the test `new_user.is_verified` equals to `False`. I don't get why is that, when I add `print(user.is_verified)` to the view, it prints `True`, but in test it's `False`.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh the object after performing the validation:

```
resp = self.client.get(link)

new_user.refresh_from_db()
```

The reason is that it is a simple value field. Such non-deferred fields do not refresh from the database automatically after the object has been created/retrieved. In other words, the value is what it was set to initially in `create_user`. To get the new value you have to refresh it.

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database).